# Error when using TextInputLayout with Github repo

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to use [this github repo](https://github.com/AckeeCZ/TextInputLayout) for implementing TextInputLayout in my project. I also added the required dependencies in my project for do so. But I am getting these errors...

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\97ed20c4805122cb37926be8f7f55040\material-1.4.0\res\values\values.xml","position":{"startLine":2751,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":187049,"endLine":2764,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":187823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\97ed20c4805122cb37926be8f7f55040\material-1.4.0\res\values\values.xml:2752:5-2765:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) filled.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\97ed20c4805122cb37926be8f7f55040\material-1.4.0\res\values\values.xml:2752:5-2765:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) filled.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

What is the error? How to fix it??

Here is my XML code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#EFE7E7">

    <cz.ackee.ui.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/colorOnBackground"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
        app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="1dp"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:hintPaddingTop="12dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Hint">

        <cz.ackee.ui.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="28dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </cz.ackee.ui.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is a weird general error, try to revert what you have done recently. sometimes it could be due to wrong assignments in resources such as assigning integer value to android:text attributes. Otherwise it could be due dependency added is conflicting with other dependencies.